# How to install zenmap on Fedora

Tags: fedora, troubleshooting, nmap

I'm trying to install Zenmap after installing Nmap however it's not quite working. I tried just the regular terminal command dnf install zenmap however it tells me that they're unable to find a match.

I then went to the official website to download the RPM file and tried using the command 'rpm -i filename.rpm' which told me I needed to download PyGTK which I did and it worked. However, now when I try to run zenmap, it shows me

File "/usr/bin/zenmap", line 182 except ImportError, e: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When I try launching zenmap from the search, it shows Zenmap GUI port Scanner but when I try clicking on it, there's a brief flash on my screen and then it's gone. I tried looking for solutions but there's only 2 when I search and neither of them has an answer to it.

I'm using Fedora 31 with KDE Plasma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Zenmap reached [EOL in F28](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/BDGROJUR2ZO6YDICSO7CA5Q3LC272WMG/) because it relies on now **deprecated** Python **2**.
See the issue on github:
[Zenmap and Ndiff are python2 only #1176](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/1176)

You should still be able to make it work by installing (deprecated) Python **2** and the necessary modules.

If I look at the [source code](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/zenmap/zenmap) zenmap relies on `/usr/bin/env python`, which on your system would normally default to **Python 3** instead of Python 2 and that's probably why you are having that syntax error. Either edit the launchers or explicitly call  Zenmap with python2 eg: `python2 /path/to/zenmap`.

Comment: Thank you! I called Zenmap with Python2 and it worked perfectly.